Angular 18 Reactive form ERROR : There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: 'q1124'
I have an angular component that will create and render a form dynamically using ReactiveFormsModule.
When I press submit it will post the data and I will get new questions for the component to render and replace the old ones.
The first render is fine when you navigate to the page.
If I submit the first question the parent will get new questions to pass down to the this component
this error : "There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: 'q1124'"
Whenever I log the form.controls it does say it contains the 'q1124'
form.component.ts

import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, Output, SimpleChanges }       from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Question } from '../../../../shared/models/views-models/question-view';
import { getQuestionAnswers } from '../../../../shared/utils/helpers.util';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCard } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-survey-form',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatCard, MatButtonModule,],
  templateUrl: './survey-form.component.html',
  styleUrl: './survey-form.component.scss'
})
export class SurveyFormComponent implements OnChanges {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  @Input() questions: Question[] = []
  @Input() currentState: string | undefined;
  @Input() previousState: string | undefined;
  @Output() dataEmitter: EventEmitter<any[]> = new EventEmitter<any[]>();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }


  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes['questions'] && changes['questions'].currentValue !== changes['questions'].previousValue) {
      this.form = this.createForm(this.fb, this.questions)
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
  }

  submit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      const answers = getQuestionAnswers(this.form, this.questions)
      this.dataEmitter.emit(answers)
    }
  }

  createForm = (
    formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    questions: any[]
  ): FormGroup => {
    const group: { [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any> } = {};

    questions.forEach(question => {
      group[question.id] = question.mandatory
        ? formBuilder.control('', [Validators.required])
        : formBuilder.control('');
    });
    return new FormGroup(group)
  }
}


form.component.html
<div class="form-container">
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()" class="input-form">
        @for (question of questions; track $index) {
        <input type="text" matInput [formControlName]="question.id" [required]="question.mandatory"
            placeholder="Type your answer here..." [id]="question.id">
        }
        @if (currentState) {
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid" mat-flat-button>Next</button>
        }
    </form>
</div>


I've tried different hooks like ngOnAfterInit to see if this could be some timing related, I also added the changeDetectorRef
UPDATE
Link to Stackblitz with mockup
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4ewzry?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-test%2Fform-test.component.ts

Create a full working example on https://stackblitz.com/ for a easy debug.

the problem is that questions have values before the form is created
You can iterate over form.controls|keyvalue
@for (control of form.controls|keyvalue; track $index) {
    <!--see that you use questions[$index].id instead of question-->
        <input type="text" matInput [formControlName]="questions[$index].id">
}

But see that you need wait to get the questions
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (
      changes['questions'] &&
      changes['questions'].currentValue !== changes['questions'].previousValue
    ) {
      //enclosed in a setTimeout without "delay"
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.form = this.createForm(this.fb, this.questions);
      })
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
  }

stackblitz

This seemed to fix the issue, kinda figured it was something  like this but new to angular and had no idea the best course of action. Thanks alot!
